# If statement check source image

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm wondering how to make an If Statement in a jquery script that checks if a source image file is a certain one, and if so execute code within If Statement. I want If Statement to execute its code only if source =

```
<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/{0}/_res/_images/icon_noticeActive.png", PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>". Here's my html code and jquery script below.

$("img#importantImg").click(function () { 
             if ($("#headerAlertMessage").is("<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/{0}/_res/_images/icon_noticeActive.png", PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>")
                $("#headerAlertMessage").show();                                                    
                $("#importantImg").attr("src", "<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/{0}/_res/_images/icon_noticeActive.png", PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>");                                            
});
```

Here's my html code that this script above references:

```
<li class="levelOne" ><a class="button notice buttonEight" href="#">
        <asp:image id="importantImg" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /></a></li>


</ul>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="contentPlaceholder1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
</div>


<div id="headerAlertMessage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none">
<div id = "divLayer1" class="alertPod">
    <img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/{0}/_res/_images/icon_alertMessage.png", PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>" />

</div>

<div id = "divLayer2" class="msgPod">
    <div id="divLayer3" class="messageWrapper">
        <h6>IMPORTANT ANNOUNCEMENT</h6>
        <div id="divLayer4" class="box" >    
            <div id = "divLayer5" class="viewport" style="overflow:   auto; height: 48px;" runat="server">
                <p>
                <asp:Literal ID="ltimportantannouncementTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
                <br />
                <asp:Literal ID="ltimportantannouncementSummary" runat="server">  </asp:Literal>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" ><img id="alertCloseBtn" ClientIDMode="Static" src="<%=     Page.ResolveUrl("~/{0}/_res/_images/button_alertMsgClose.png",  PBS.Cms.Settings.PBSFolderName) %>" /></a>   

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img[src="your_source_goes_here.jpg"]').each(function (index, value) {
    //run your code here
});
```

This will find all images with a specific source, iterate through them, which allows you to do whatever you want inside the `.each()` function. Note that `value` is the variable that holds the reference to the image within the `.each()` function.

Here is a jsfiddle of selecting images by their source: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/u5xWP/

Comment: @jre247 If you like the answer, then you should accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left.